# How do unwrap fisheye and overlap fisheye lens with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I am using an insta 360 x3 and would like to automate exporting videos without using their studio tools on Linux.

Here's a screencap of a video format in the camera (Insta360 x3 camera screenshot):

[image: Insta360 x3 camera screenshot]

---

I am using ffmpeg to unwrap the video feed with the following command: ([taken from this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58336312/4581431))

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.lrv -vf v360=dfisheye:e:yaw=-90 -c:v libx265 -b:v 40000k -bufsize 5000k -preset ultrafast -c:a copy -t 10 test.mkv
```

The command works, and does a decent job, but one of the lens has a higher field of view with a fuzzy outline. This results in the following image:

Image of Insta360 x3 camera screenshot after ffmpeg command:
[image: Image of Insta360 x3 camera screenshot after ffmpeg command]

---

Is there a way to change the ffmpeg command to either overlap both lenses by a couple pixels to remove the fuzz, or crop out the overlapping field of view?

Answer (score 1):

The command you are using uses default paramters, which means it assumes that your cameras have FOV=180 and it's perfectly horizontal.

After some experiments with [this site](https://ffmpeg.lav.io/) I found that actual FOV is 193°; but that's not enough: of course it's impossible to hold the camera perfectly horizontal, so you have to compensate pitch and roll.

The final command I got is:

```
ffmpeg -i dfisheye.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v]v360=input=dfisheye:output=equirect:pitch=-22:roll=-20:ih_fov=193:iv_fov=193[out_v]" -map "[out_v]" out.gif
```

Or, using you syntax:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.lrv -vf v360=dfisheye:e:pitch=-22:roll=-20:ih_fov=193:iv_fov=193 -c:v libx265 -b:v 40000k -bufsize 5000k -preset ultrafast -c:a copy -t 10 test.mkv
```

The image I get is:

[image]

Pay attention not to confuse **ih_fov** with **h_fov** and **iv_fov** with **v_fov** .

Please note that once you find the right FOV for your camera, it will remain the same for all your photos, but PICTH and ROLL will be different for each photo; consider that a perfectly horizontal photo would fit in such a grid:

[image: equirect grid]

Your image without compensating for pitch and roll:

[image: raw]

Answer (score 0):

This script will not correct for lens vignetting darkened stitch edge. Changing the output file `NEW.mp4` to photo extension `NEW.jpg` will not pass photo without deleting `libx264 -preset ultrafast`.

The value H is height of video. You need to set to your input video height. The FOV should be set to your camera FOV.

The C value is the number of pixels of blending between the two images where they overlap.

```
@echo off

REM split the input and pitch one to level them - hstack the two streams to the output

set "FOV=189.1"       :: Horizontal and vertical field of view of the fisheye lenses in degrees, normal 189.1
set "H=1920"    ::Height of video
set "C=2"   :: Width of interpolation band in degrees, must be smaller or equal than (FOV-180 ), normal is 2
set "RL=0"  ::Roll (neg cockwise/counter clockwise pos) angle to change perspective in Left Equirectangular image
set "PL=0"  ::Pitch (pos down/up neg) angle degrees to boundary to change perspective in Left Equirectangular image
set "YL=0"  ::Yaw (pos left/right neg) angle degrees to change perspective in Left Equirectangular image, normal is -1
set "RR=0"  ::Roll (neg cockwise/counter clockwise pos) angle to change perspective in Right Equirectangular imag, normal 1
set "PR=0"  ::Pitch (pos down/up neg) angle degrees to boundary to change perspective in Right Equirectangular image
set "YR=0"  ::Yaw (pos left/right neg) angle degrees to change perspective in Right Equirectangular image MUST NOT BE POSITIVE AS GREATER THAN 180 NOT POSSIBLE

REM  Create the mergemap file

ffmpeg -f lavfi -i nullsrc=size=%H%x%H% -vf "format=gray8,geq='clip(128-128/%C%*(180-%FOV%/(%H%/2)*hypot(X-%H%/2,Y-%H%/2)),0,255)',v360=input=fisheye:output=e:ih_fov=%FOV%:iv_fov=%FOV%" -frames:v 1 -y mergemap.png

REM Convert file Dual_Feye to equirectangular projection

ffmpeg -i %1 -i %FF%mergemap.png -lavfi "[0]format=rgb24,split[a][b];[a]crop=ih:iw/2:0:0,v360=input=fisheye:output=e:ih_fov=%FOV%:iv_fov=%FOV%:yaw=%YL%:pitch=%PL%:roll=%RL%[c];[b]crop=ih:iw/2:iw/2:0,v360=input=fisheye:output=e:yaw=180+%YR%:pitch=%PR%:roll=%RR%:ih_fov=%FOV%:iv_fov=%FOV%[d];[1]format=gbrp[e];[c][d][e]maskedmerge" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -q:v 1 -y NEW.mp4
```